# Typescript import import angular2 router errors

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am using the following import statement in my TypeScript code

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
```

I have a few questions about this

1. What does the "@" symbol mean in `"@angular/router"`
2. I am using angular2 when I try to compile I get the following error `cannot find module @angular/router`. I am using `"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",`

Comment: I believe the @angular will point to your angular installation location as angular/router is an angular component with its own library. @ is simply stating the directory the angular package is installed in. As for the missing module, make sure you're using the latest angular package (2.0.0-beta.17 is the latest). It might be that your version is missing the router component. Please don't take my answer as gospel, as I'm not 100% certain this is correct. Hope it helps though.

Answer (score 0):

> What does the "@" symbol mean in "@angular/router"

The '@' is just the name of the library. If you look at the systemjs.config at the bottom of the [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) on angular.io-s web site that's how it's mapped.

Also if you look in to the package.json file. '@angular/...' is the literal name of the package.

> I am using angular2 when I try to compile I get the following error cannot find module @angular/router. I am using "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7"

Firstly you should really consider updating to the new version 'RC5' there were a bunch of breaking changes and fixes.

The reason why you get the error `cannot find module @angular/router` is probably because you have it mapped wrongly in your systemjs config or you're trying to install a version of the 'router' that doesn't exist.

I think you should really try to follow the 5 Min Quickstarter to set up the initial project and then follow the [Routing and Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) documentation for the routing part.